# Selenium JavaScript Change default_directory

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

how to change the default_directory of download with JavaScript ?
i have folder list say shes name is
"C:\Study\Selenium"
how to change the location of the download file to this path ?
this part of my code

```
 chromeOptions.setUserPreferences('download.default_directory': "C:\Study\Selenuim");
    chromeOptions.setUserPreferences({'download.prompt_for_download': false});
    chromeOptions.setUserPreferences({'download.directory_upgrade': true});
```

but its not change the location  of the folder

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure out solution. It should be:

```
    const chromePrefs = ({'download.default_directory':"C:\\Study\\Selenuim"})
    const chromeOptions = new chrome.Options().setUserPreferences(chromePrefs)
```